# Is it worthwhile to use Metro UI in a new WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, java-metro-framework

I'm going to start a new `WPF` project and I'm considering to implement it by the `Metro UI` approach.

As this UI isn't yet popular, and also my project will release in early 2012, does it worth to implement Metro UI in my application or not?

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, it is worthwhile because Microsoft is advertising it, a wide variety of applications will release with this UI, users are exited to use this new UI, and this is an opportunity that you can make for yourself.

In addition in the near future most of the Custom Control companies will make a new control for it just like Ribbon. I know that ribbon wasn't a complete UI but it shows that Microsot UI approacehs are worth to try

Comment: @Nezhad, The problem with Metro UI is that defining a form for itis not an easy job,it takes more time than a simple form.

Answer (score 6):

The Metro UI is designed with touch-based computing in mind - Think about how your project will be used, is it likely that people using your applications will be using touchscreens?

Also consider who you're aiming your project at:
Corporates tend to wait a while before migrating to a new OS, so they're likely to stick with Windows 7 for some time.
On the flipside, if your project is aimed at the general public, then it might be "cool" and make for a good marketing feature.

Comment: I don't agree with you in the case of touch ability. You know Windows 8 isnot going to use only in touchscreens, most of peopl will have it with simple monitors, I believe that it works better with touchscreens but has its own advantages without touch abilities.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, I think that it's worth since the next version of Windows 8 will have a metro enabled desktop, take a look [at this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p92QfWOw88I)

Comment: the point is that users arenot familiar to work with it yet, and we have to put some time teach them how to use it. and it is costly. isn't it?